# React-native native module possibilities for background task on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process, react-native-ios

My Problem: I have an app that communicates with a medical BLE device.  I have it all working but my problem is that when an ios user puts the app in the background I stop getting/processing the messages sent via bluetooth.  Android seems to keep getting these messages but from what I've found, on iOS, the JS bridge is torn down and there isn't a solution out there for this problem.  The phone must continue to process the data sent from the BLE device.

My thought is this and this is my question for you all.
Would it be possible to create a native module for ios that will always be running and be doing the following: getting ble data as it is notified.  Store that data to the file system and push it to a webservice all while the app is in the background?  It would also be great to have the ability to read the fs created files and show some data about them when the app comes back to the foreground.  Would this be possible?

Do you know of another option that could work?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm building something with similar requirements (recieve data in background via bluetooth), but not sure how to set up the background process– could you help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK as I was heading down the native path and reading on the ios bluetooth schtuff I found this article [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) and specifically it mentions a plist setting.

> The Core Bluetooth background execution modes are declared by adding the **UIBackgroundModes** key to your Info.plist file and setting the key’s value to an array containing one of the following strings:
>   **bluetooth-central** —The app communicates with Bluetooth low energy peripherals using the Core Bluetooth framework.
>   **bluetooth-peripheral** —The app shares data using the Core Bluetooth framework.

So I thought to myself, would just by adding these keys to my xcode project that iOS would be smart enough and not care that I am a RN app and not native... well that was the ticket!  I plugged these values in and the ble data is processed even when I open another app.  "Wallah!" ;)

Comment: have you used one of the strings (which one) or both?

Comment: @julio I am using both but I think the Central role should be enough.

Comment: @RobelRobelLingstuyl thanks for sharing this! the guide was pretty useful. I found this other guide which was also useful: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Background-mode-(iOS) 

Also, unrelated, but I saw your bio, that you're looking for remote 20-30hr/week work, and maybe I have something– I'd love to chat :) 

Drop me a line to joao[at]minthouse[dot]dev

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable iOS background mode capability in your Xcode project settings.

Also take a look at [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx) which provides background support for both iOS and Android.

Comment: thank you! btw I'm using react-native-ble-manager.  Can you speak to one being better than the other?

Comment: Since I have no experience on developing BLE app, I cannot give a good suggestion. I think you have to provide `restoreIdentifierKey` option too for react-native-ble-manager to make background mode working. Anyway, both should rely on iOS Background Mode capability to keep running in background, so you have to enable this capability in your Xcode.

Comment: I've been using react-native-ble-plx and struggling, and it seems react-native-ble-manager is more common. What method are you using to recieve the information, and how have you configured it to work in background? I'd really appreciate any help!!