# Is it possible to run a React Native iOS app as a daemon?

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios-bluetooth

I am making an iOS app using React Native.

Is it possible to create a daemon app that detects the Bluetooth state and performs an action even when the app is closed instead of in the background state?

In the article below, through the state and restore function of Core Bluetooth, even if the app is closed, can I run it again in the background and perform the desired operation?

[Core Bluetooth Background Processing for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)

Comment: I think you can find what you want here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802451/react-native-native-module-possibilities-for-background-task-on-ios

Comment: It depends on what you want to do precisely. You can reconnect to a previously discovered peripheral, receive data from a currently connected peripheral and be alerted to a newly discovered peripheral that is advertising a specific servicehat you are interested in